# linq for a for loop inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can anyone help me on how to convert the following c# code to use linq to sql? By using linq to sql, would that execute faster or would it still be the same as below?

```
foreach (var a in all)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a.Items[i].Item.TruckItemID.Equals(CarItem.CarItemID))
               {
                   allItems = a.Items[i];
               }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A tool like resharper often suggests loop to linq conversions and might be a good way to learn: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want something like:

```
allItems = all.SelectMany(a => a.Items)
              .Where(a => a.Item.TruckItemID.Equals(CarItem.CarItemID));
```

Keep in mind, though, that the execution isn't going to speed up. LINQ will expand your query into nearly the same code.

Comment: thanks for the information. I always thought linq will execute faster. good to know for knowledge/future references.

Answer (score 1):

Linq 2 Sql is a database access technology that translates LINQ into SQL Commands and executes them on the database. It returns data into in-memory collections. Since for loops are very primitive they tend to be good on speed if used properly. Once you begin nesting for-loops your operation will become exponentially slower as data increase O(n^2).